# share value between html tags in ngrepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have ngrepeat displaying: filter name, next to it counter of selected values and button only visible when counter > 0

```
<li  ng-repeat="filterType in filters"  >                           
    <span ng-bind="filterType.name"></span>
    <span ng-bind="getSelectedValueCount(filterType.id)"> </span>
    <button type="button" class="close"  ng-if="getSelectedValueCount(filterType.id) > 0  ">Close</button>
</li>
```

At the moment I am calling `getSelectedValueCount(filterType.id)` twice. Would it be possible to call it once and share value between two html tags?

I have tried to use ng-init but it didn't quite work - values were not refreshing.

```
<li  ng-repeat="filterType in filters" ng-init="myValue = getSelectedValueCount(filterType.id);" ng-model="myValue " >                          
    <span ng-bind="filterType.name"></span>
    <span ng-bind="myValue"> </span>
    <button type="button" class="close"  ng-if="myValue > 0  ">Close</button>
</li>
```

Comment: Did you try to add the ng-init directive to the second `span`element?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the corresponding variable within the ng-bind directive instead of ng-init, because ng-init is only used once:

```js
  
  function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var i = 1;

    $scope.calc = function(id) {
      return id - i;
    }
    $scope.filters =[
      {name: "name1", id: 1},
      {name: "name2", id: 2},
      {name: "name3", id: 3},
      {name: "name4", id: 4}
    ];
    $scope.changeCalc = function() {
      i++;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <li  ng-repeat="filterType in filters"  >                           
      <span ng-bind="filterType.name"></span>
      <span ng-bind="value = calc(filterType.id)"> </span>
      <button type="button" class="close"  ng-if="value > 0">Close</button>
    </li>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="changeCalc()">Increment i</button>
    <br />
    Current calc(1): {{calc(1)}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it because you init value to 1 (id: 2 -1 ) where in my case it all starts at 0 and then is not refreshed

Comment: You mean that the return value of calc changes after the ng-repeat is initialized?

Comment: I have replaced my nginit with ngbind and it works , thank you